# How to set new session on each href click in php

Tags: php, mysql, session

i want to set the session on click.

i have a page mylinks.php and fetch the data from mysql

```
while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{
 echo "<a href='get.php?id=".$row[0]."'>".$row[1]."</a>";
}
```

i just want to create a new session when click on links. and use them on another page. i want to create the session on source page not on the next page.

And the session created on the mylinks.php is unset on the get.php
So on every new click a new session is created on source page i.e mylinks.php page.

Please help me to solve this.

Edit:- i want that the content of the get.php is shown only when user is coming from the mylinks.php page.

Comment: You need to learn the difference between html, javascript and php. What you ask, is not possible. You can only set the session on another page, because you require user interaction first.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: You could hack your way around setting a session via an ajax call on click, I guess. But it may not work as you'd expect it to work.

Comment: Yes i should try it with ajax call. but still dont know how to hack in that way. @AndreiP.

Comment: @sking i am edit my question. so its clarify what i am exactly want to do is.

Comment: @PreeT why do u need session for that ? just use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

Comment: @PreeT Your question dosn't really make sense at all, can you please I believe there are either terms that you are significantly mis-using or or there is a lot being lost in the translation.

Comment: @sking with '$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']' the query string is shown too. but i just want the page url without query string.

Comment: @PreeT use this `strtok(basename($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']),'?')` to get page name without query string

Comment: @sking thankx yeah this will works.

Comment: @PreeT you dont need to filter it.Its safe to use directly. `filter_input` doesn't work with `INPUT_SERVER or INPUT_ENV` at least on my server as this comment suggest http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php#77307

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use php sessions for what you are trying to accomplish, you can do it easier way.

You should create a unique token value and store it on `$_SESSION['token']` on mylinks.php page in the beginning. Also you should set that value as query string on the link such as `echo"<a href='get.php?id=".$row[0]."&token=".$_SESSION['token']."'>$row[1]</a>";`

Now on the get.php page, you can use the following condition to see if it is actually referred by mylinks.php page or not

```
if(isset($_GET['token']) && $_GET['token'] == $_SESSION['token']) {
     //Token matche, so a valid request
     $_SESSION['token'] = "";
}
else {
    //Invalid request
}
```